# specify global settings for Json.Net for DateTime serialization/deserialization

Tags: json.net

Is it possible to set JSON.Net such that if you want to serialize a DateTime, it is serialized to UTC format. When deserializing from a string, it is deserialized to 'LocalTime'.  For example:

- Serialization
- - 01/01/2012 16:00:00 (Kind = UTC) Stored as `2012-01-01T16:00:00Z`
- - 01/01/2012 16:00:00 (Kind = Local, with GMT +1) -> Stored as `2012-01-01T15:00:00Z`
- Deserialization (assuming machine with Local Time = GMT+1)
- - `2012-01-01T16:00:00Z` -> Deserialized to 01/01/2012 17:00 +1GMT (Kind = Local)
- - `2012-01-01T15:00:00Z` -> Deserialized to 01/01/2012 16:00 +1GMT (Kind = Local)

However, I would like this to happen 'automatically', and not having to specify it with setttings each time - Like a global setting. Is this possible?

Answer (score 6):

In ASP.NET WebAPI, it is possible. Try this:

```csharp
// Converters will be userd during serialization (override DateTimeZoneHandling)
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new IsoDateTimeConverter { DateTimeStyles = DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal });
// DateTimeZoneHandling will be effective during deserialization
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.DateTimeZoneHandling = DateTimeZoneHandling.Local;
```

Comment: I have been trying `DateTimeZoneHandling` with default settings but couldn't get it to work. Probably because default settings applies to both serializer and deserializer.

Answer (score 1):

Just as a note for future reference, the 'fix' to this was not to use `DateTime` but `DateTimeOffset`, as `DateTime` can bring various confusion regarding to the timezone it is actually in.

There is no ambiguity in storing a `DateTimeOffset` as it is stored always including the timezone, and always refers to the same point in time no matter where / when.